# Kafka Connect Custom Transformation : want to transform the data adding custom fields only once (not to all columns)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using kafka connect source connector to stream a table record to Kafka topics. I want to transform the data while reading like below :

If My table is like below :

{"author": "Philip K. Dick", "character": "Palmer Eldritch"}

I want to convert it into :

{"id":"123", "type":"test" , "timestamp":"1234567",{"author": "Philip K. Dick", "character": "Palmer Eldritch"}}

with the examples I have seen in Kafka Connect Transformations it is transforming all the columns/records in the given table.
But I want to add/append few static fields only once .
Can someone help me with some working example or some reference where to look.

I have tried using

"transforms": "insertStaticField1,insertStaticField2"

but it adds the static field to all the columns of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unclear what you mean "only once". Each record is a unique event. Every event is passed to a transform. Transforms will always be applied to all records; they are not meant to single-out specific records.

The `InsertField` transform does not create nested fields, only adds fields to the top-most object (they are not called columns, here).

In order to "wrap" a record in a new object, for instance `data` in `{"id":"123", "type":"test" , "timestamp":"1234567", "data": {"author": "Philip K. Dick", "character": "Palmer Eldritch"}}` you'd need `HoistField`, but that only applies to single fields, not multiple.

Therefore, if you want this type of logic, then use Kafka Streams or ksqlDB, for example if you are unwilling to create a custom transform.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your response . by once I mean when I read data from the table it can have multiple records like below :                                                                                      
          Author          character
1 Philip K. Dick  Palmer Eldritch
2 John            xyz                         and I want to transform it into    : {"id":"123", "type":"test" , "timestamp":"1234567",{"author": "Philip K. Dick", "character": "Palmer Eldritch"},{"author": "John", "character": "xyz"}}

Comment: Like I said, each event is unique. **Single Message** Transforms, as they are called, don't combine "multiple records". Plus, your example there isn't valid JSON

Comment: I am using Avro not json and I cant not post the actual data so I just created a sample mimicking the data format.  I got your point though . Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have one question regarding custom transform , If I want to insert a new field with dynamic value (like UUID) how can I achieve that ? I am new to Kafka connect and I am not sure how the custom Transform works

Comment: They are Java classes https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/custom.html#custom-transformations